# Converting between Fahrenheit and Celsius

Tags: ruby, converting

I'm learning Ruby and working through some exercises. I completed the following exercise without truly understanding why and how it works. I know that's an embarrassing thing to say but I feel like my subconscious mind wrote the code and conscious me (or maybe unconscious me you could say) is having trouble understanding why and how it works and if it's even written correctly.

I would appreciate if someone can run through this code and give me a breakdown of how it works and if you think it's written well.

**My Code**

```
class Temperature

  class << self
    def from_fahrenheit temp
      Temperature.new({f: temp})
    end

    def from_celsius temp
      Temperature.new({c: temp})
    end
  end

  def initialize(options={})
    @f = options[:f]
    @c = options[:c]
  end

  def in_fahrenheit
    return @f if @f
    (@c * (9.0 / 5.0)) + 32
  end

  def in_celsius
    return @c if @c
    (@f - 32) * 5.0 / 9.0
  end
end

class Celsius < Temperature
  def initialize temp
    super(c: temp)
  end
end

class Fahrenheit < Temperature
  def initialize temp
    super(f: temp)
  end
end
```

**Rspec Test**

```
describe Temperature do

  describe "can be constructed with an options hash" do
    describe "in degrees fahrenheit" do
      it "at 50 degrees" do
        Temperature.new(:f => 50).in_fahrenheit.should == 50
      end

      describe "and correctly convert to celsius" do
        it "at freezing" do
          Temperature.new(:f => 32).in_celsius.should == 0
        end

        it "at boiling" do
          Temperature.new(:f => 212).in_celsius.should == 100
        end

        it "at body temperature" do
          Temperature.new(:f => 98.6).in_celsius.should == 37
        end

        it "at an arbitrary temperature" do
          Temperature.new(:f => 68).in_celsius.should == 20
        end
      end
    end

    describe "in degrees celsius" do
      it "at 50 degrees" do
        Temperature.new(:c => 50).in_celsius.should == 50
      end

      describe "and correctly convert to fahrenheit" do
        it "at freezing" do
          Temperature.new(:c => 0).in_fahrenheit.should == 32
        end

        it "at boiling" do
          Temperature.new(:c => 100).in_fahrenheit.should == 212
        end

        it "at body temperature" do
          Temperature.new(:c => 37).in_fahrenheit.should be_within(0.1).of(98.6)
        end
      end
    end
  end


  describe "can be constructed via factory methods" do

    it "in degrees celsius" do
      Temperature.from_celsius(50).in_celsius.should == 50
      Temperature.from_celsius(50).in_fahrenheit.should == 122
    end

    it "in degrees fahrenheit" do
      Temperature.from_fahrenheit(50).in_fahrenheit.should == 50
      Temperature.from_fahrenheit(50).in_celsius.should == 10
    end

  end


  describe "utility class methods" do

  end

  # Here's another way to solve the problem!
  describe "Temperature subclasses" do
    describe "Celsius subclass" do
      it "is constructed in degrees celsius" do
        Celsius.new(50).in_celsius.should == 50
        Celsius.new(50).in_fahrenheit.should == 122
      end

      it "is a Temperature subclass" do
        Celsius.new(0).should be_a(Temperature)
      end
    end

    describe "Fahrenheit subclass" do
      it "is constructed in degrees fahrenheit" do
        Fahrenheit.new(50).in_fahrenheit.should == 50
        Fahrenheit.new(50).in_celsius.should == 10
      end

      it "is a Temperature subclass" do
        Fahrenheit.new(0).should be_a(Temperature)
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For someone who wasn't conscious when he wrote this code, it looks quite nice :)

Some observations:

**Tests should do only one thing**

This is OK in most of your tests, but you got a little 'lazy' at the last two tests - make a different test for each `should`. You could use RSpec's [one-liner](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/subject/one-liner-syntax) syntax, just for the fun of it:

```
 describe "in degrees celsius" do
   subject { Temperature.from_celsius(50) }

   its (:in_celsius) { should == 50 }
   its (:in_fahrenheit) { should == 122 }
 end
```

**Meaningful Names**

Again, in most cases, you are doing fine, and there may even be good arguments to say that `@f` and `@c` are clear enough in context, but there really is no reason not to call them `@fahrenheit` and `@celsius`. `temp` is also a quirk you should fix...

**When things don't change**

After you create a `Temperature` instance, its `celsius` and `fahrenheit` values will never change, so there is no reason why you should continue to calculate them - simply store the result in the appropriate member:

```
  def in_fahrenheit
    return @f if @f
    @f = (@c * (9.0 / 5.0)) + 32
  end
```

You can even make this shorter, using the `||=` operator, which will compute and assign the member if it is not assigned:

```
  def in_fahrenheit
    @f ||= (@c * (9.0 / 5.0)) + 32
  end
```

This is looking more and more like a getter function, and really, since it calls for the state of the instance, you don't need to imply there is ever a calculation, simply call it `fahrenheit`:

```
def fahrenheit
  @fahrenheit ||= (@celsius * (9.0 / 5.0)) + 32
end
```

**Have a consistent style**

In your code you call methods with hashes with three different styles:

```
Temperature.new({f: temp})
super(c: temp)
Temperature.new(:c => 50).in_celsius.should == 50
```

All of these styles work, but it is better to choose one, and stick with it. When using a hash in method, my favorite is the second style (`Temperature.new(f: temp)`)

**Use language features**

Since Ruby 2.0, [named parameters](http://dev.af83.com/2013/02/18/ruby-2-0-keyword-arguments.html) are supported, and you are encouraged to use it. It will give you free validation, as any parameter which is not one of those you declared, an error will be issued:

```
def initialize(celsius: nil, fahrenheit: nil)
  @fahrenheit = fahrenheit
  @celsius = celsius
end
```

One last point, regarding your `Celsius` and `Fahrenheit` classes, I personally don't see any utility in having them, since they add no logic besides a construction convenience, and may even confuse, since their name implies they support only one scale or the other...

So now, your class will look like this:

```
class Temperature

  class << self
    def from_fahrenheit fahrenheit
      Temperature.new(fahrenheit: fahrenheit)
    end

    def from_celsius celsius
      Temperature.new(celsius: celsius)
    end
  end

  def initialize(celsius: nil, fahrenheit: nil)
    @fahrenheit = fahrenheit
    @celsius = celsius
  end

  def fahrenheit
    @fahrenheit ||= (@celsius * (9.0 / 5.0)) + 32
  end

  def celsius
    @celsius ||= (@fahrenheit - 32) * 5.0 / 9.0
  end
end
```

Comment: +1. I'd probably pre-calculate C/F values in initialization to avoid ugly memoizations.

Comment: @Uri Thank you for your time. I think your answer is fantastic and all of your points valid. I appreciate all of your suggestions and the links too. I'd like to point out that I did not write the test spec. So using (named params) `(celsius: nil, fahrenheit: nil)` would require I change the test spec which isn't allowed. Regardless I will use these techniques in my personal work. Thanks again. +1

Comment: You can still use named params, only you won't be able to change parameter names: `def initialize(c: nil, f: nil)`

Comment: One question about your `initialize` - what if the user gives values for both `celsius` and `fahrenheit` and the two are inconsistent, e.g., `Temperature.new(fahrenheit: 98.6, celsius: 0)`?  There should be some sort of consistency check.

Comment: @pjs You are absolutely right, there should also be a check for someone giving _no_ values.